# WPF - How to get ActualHeight of ContentControl's content?

Tags: wpf, animation

Here's some code:

```
<components:AnimatedContentControl x:Name="MainContent" Content="{Binding}">
    <components:AnimatedContentControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="components:AnimatedContentControl.ContentChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                         Storyboard.TargetName="MainContent"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                         Duration="0:0:0.25"
                         From="0"
                         To="{Binding ElementName=MainContent, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </components:AnimatedContentControl.Triggers>
</components:AnimatedContentControl>
```

`AnimatedContentControl` is a class I created, based off of a ContentControl, which has a `ContentChanged` routed event inside it (since for whatever reason, `ContentControl`s don't have a `ContentChanged` event by default).

The goal in this code is for whatever is pointed to by my application's `DataContext` to be loaded into this `ContentControl`, and when the data context is changed, to show a simple animation consisting of a slide from zero to the size of the new content (ideally, it would slide from the height of the old content to the height of the new content, but first steps first).  For such a simple idea, this has been monstrously hard to develop.

I already know what my problem is: when this event fires, the `Content` property of the `AnimatedContentControl` has been updated, but for some reason, the `ActualSize` of the `AnimatedContentControl` has not (actually, come to think of it, I could probably use the `ActualSize` property for the `From` property of the `DoubleAnimation` - I'll try that later).

So my question is this: is there something I can bind to in the `DoubleAnimation` which is the actual size of the `AnimatedContentControl`'s content?  If so, what is it?  If not, what workaround options are there?

Comment: Sry, typing from a tablet and posted too early. WPF elements have no actual size until they are in a layout, since they can fill parent, etc, so their actual size is dependent of the available space in the parent and other conditions. To get to the ActualSize for a new element before you add it somewhere you must call Measure and Arrange, look them up at MSDN. When you put an element in a visible parent Measure and Arrange gets called automatically, but in your case that is too late, since you want to animate to a new size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boris was right - my code now looks like this:

```
<components:AnimateableContentControl x:Name="MainContent" Content="{Binding}">
    <components:AnimateableContentControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="components:AnimateableContentControl.ContentChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        x:Name="TransitionAnimation"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MainContent"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                        Duration="0:0:0.25"
                        From="0"
                        To="0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </components:AnimateableContentControl.Triggers>
</components:AnimateableContentControl>
```

...and where I change `DataContext`s (causing the animation), I have this:

```
DataTemplate template = Resources[new DataTemplateKey(m_currentViewModel.GetType())] as DataTemplate;

if (template == null)
{
    DataContext = m_currentViewModel;
    return;
}

FrameworkElement element = template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;

if (element == null)
{
    DataContext = m_currentViewModel;
    return;
}

element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

TransitionAnimation.To = element.DesiredSize.Height;

DataContext = m_currentViewModel;
```

Works like a charm! Thanks, Boris!